# Generic lifetime parameter of the iterator creeping into the struct type

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I am trying to create a data structure (let's call it `Outer`) that wraps another data structure (let's call it `Inner`). However, rather than fixing an implementation for `Inner`, I want to use a trait so that I can easily swap the implementation of this underlying data structure.

A simplified version would look somewhat like this:

```rust
pub struct Outer<K, V, I>
where
    I: Inner<K, V>
{
    inner: I,
    // some phantom data fields
}

pub trait Inner<K, V>
{
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to add an iterator to `Outer` which should also wrap an iterator provided by the inner data structure, and here comes the problem.

In the `Inner` trait, I cannot write:

```rust
fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&'_ K, &'_ V)>;
```

as `impl Trait` syntax is not allowed here, and I also cannot introduce an associated type like:

```rust
type Iterator<'a>: Iterator<Item = (&'a K, &'a V)>;
```

since [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265) are not there yet.

What I came up with so far is to have a separate trait for an iterator:

```rust
pub trait InnerIterator<'a, K: 'a, V: 'a>: Iterator<Item = (&'a K, &'a V)> {
    type Inner: Inner<K, V>;

    fn new(inner: &'a Self::Inner) -> Self;
}
```

Then `Outer` receives a new generic type parameter `InnerIt`:

```rust
pub struct Outer<K, V, I, InnerIt>
where
    I: Inner<K, V>
{
    inner: I,
    // some phantom data fields
}

impl<K, V, I, InnerIt> Outer<K, V, I, InnerIt> {
    pub fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> InnerIt
    where
        I: Inner<K, V>,
        InnerIt: InnerIterator<'a, K, V, Inner = I>,
        K: 'a,
        V: 'a,
    {
        InnerIt::new(&self.inner)
    }
}
```

And now, when I want to pick some specific `Inner` implementation, I have something like:

```rust
pub type SomeOuter<'a, K, V> = Outer<K, V, SomeInner<K, V>, SomeInnerIterator<'a, K, V>>;
```

and here the lifetime parameter `'a` becomes a part of my type definition.

Other than the problem that I would have to add at least two more parameters for enabling `iter_mut` and `into_iter`, my question is what would be the consequences of having this `'a` parameter there, would it continue to propagate further when using this type, would the user of this type be surprised by this lifetime parameter, and is there a way to implement iterators without introducing generic iterator types and their lifetimes for `Outer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it continue to propagate further when using this type

Any type that wants to embed your type would need to also have a lifetime parameter.
However, some places lifetime elision will take over (e.g. in function arguments):

```rust
struct Struct1<'a>(std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>);
struct Struct2<'a>(Struct1<'a>); // lifetime propagates to Struct2

fn func(_: Struct1){
    println!("lifetime not needed. It is 'elided'");
}
```

> would the user of this type be surprised by this lifetime parameter

They shouldn't be. In rust, lifetime are everywhere. For example, iterating over a slice is done using a [struct with a lifetime parameter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#method.as_slice).

> is there a way to implement iterators without introducing generic iterator types and their lifetimes for Outer?

The reason why you have a lifetime parameter is that you have an iterator that returns a reference. If your iterator would return a direct object no lifetime would be needed. For example, if you turn a vector into an iterator (which thus returns all the elements in the vector) [it won't need a lifetime parameter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still feel that something is fishy with this lifetime though, that it's on the type and not only on the `iter` method. And it's not ideal that it would propagate to all structs owning my data structure. Oh well, I guess I will wait for generic associated types and remove the trait for the time being.